# tidy select syntax for multiple variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I have been unable to find a good example of how to use across/c_across with tidy select syntax to select variables that contain multiple strings. I find str_detect works well, but it doesnt seem to work inside dplyr verbs?
The first line of summarise works in the code, but am looking for correct syntax to find variables containing both substrings in second and third line:

```
dput(image[1,])
structure(list(Image = "B07", Match = 1, Stage = "pT2a N1", stage = "IIB", 
    `Molecular profile` = "WT", `Num Detections` = 686184, `Num CD68 (Opal 780)` = 19698, 
    `Num CD68 (Opal 780): FoxP3 (Opal 570)` = 425, `Num CD8 (Opal 480)` = 20576, 
    `Num CD8 (Opal 480): FoxP3 (Opal 570)` = 733, `Num CD8 (Opal 480): PD-1 (Opal 620)` = 4663, 
    `Num CD8 (Opal 480): PanCK (Opal 690)` = 7188, `Num FoxP3 (Opal 570)` = 5927, 
    `Num PD-1 (Opal 620)` = 12466, `Num PD-1 (Opal 620): CD68 (Opal 780)` = 928, 
    `Num PD-1 (Opal 620): FoxP3 (Opal 570)` = 740, `Num PD-L1 (Opal 520)` = 6809, 
    `Num PD-L1 (Opal 520): CD68 (Opal 780)` = 1903, `Num PD-L1 (Opal 520): PD-1 (Opal 620)` = 3655, 
    `Num PD-L1 (Opal 520): PD-1 (Opal 620): CD68 (Opal 780)` = 558, 
    `Num PD-L1 (Opal 520): PD-1 (Opal 620): FoxP3 (Opal 570)` = 306, 
    `Num PD-L1 (Opal 520): PanCK (Opal 690)` = 4462, `Num PD-L1 (Opal 520): PanCK (Opal 690): CD68 (Opal 780)` = 1570, 
    `Num PD-L1 (Opal 520): PanCK (Opal 690): PD-1 (Opal 620)` = 1417, 
    `Num PanCK (Opal 690)` = 296647, `Num PanCK (Opal 690): CD68 (Opal 780)` = 15629, 
    `Num PanCK (Opal 690): FoxP3 (Opal 570)` = 3845, `Num PanCK (Opal 690): PD-1 (Opal 620)` = 7433, 
    `Num PanCK (Opal 690): PD-1 (Opal 620): CD68 (Opal 780)` = 557, 
    `Num PanCK (Opal 690): PD-1 (Opal 620): FoxP3 (Opal 570)` = 286, 
    `Num CD8 (Opal 480): PD-L1 (Opal 520)` = 6252, `Num CD8 (Opal 480): PanCK (Opal 690): FoxP3 (Opal 570)` = 186, 
    `Num CD8 (Opal 480): CD68 (Opal 780)` = 1244, `Num CD8 (Opal 480): CD68 (Opal 780): FoxP3 (Opal 570)` = 58, 
    `Num CD8 (Opal 480): PD-1 (Opal 620): CD68 (Opal 780)` = 296, 
    `Num CD8 (Opal 480): PD-1 (Opal 620): CD68 (Opal 780): FoxP3 (Opal 570)` = 17, 
    `Num CD8 (Opal 480): PD-1 (Opal 620): FoxP3 (Opal 570)` = 215, 
    `Num CD8 (Opal 480): PD-L1 (Opal 520): CD68 (Opal 780)` = 614, 
    `Num CD8 (Opal 480): PD-L1 (Opal 520): FoxP3 (Opal 570)` = 322, 
    `Num CD8 (Opal 480): PD-L1 (Opal 520): PD-1 (Opal 620)` = 3454, 
    `Num CD8 (Opal 480): PD-L1 (Opal 520): PD-1 (Opal 620): CD68 (Opal 780)` = 358, 
    `Num CD8 (Opal 480): PD-L1 (Opal 520): PD-1 (Opal 620): FoxP3 (Opal 570)` = 213, 
    `Num CD8 (Opal 480): PD-L1 (Opal 520): PanCK (Opal 690)` = 2263, 
    `Num CD8 (Opal 480): PD-L1 (Opal 520): PanCK (Opal 690): CD68 (Opal 780)` = 249, 
    `Num CD8 (Opal 480): PD-L1 (Opal 520): PanCK (Opal 690): FoxP3 (Opal 570)` = 69, 
    `Num CD8 (Opal 480): PD-L1 (Opal 520): PanCK (Opal 690): PD-1 (Opal 620)` = 1763, 
    `Num CD8 (Opal 480): PD-L1 (Opal 520): PanCK (Opal 690): PD-1 (Opal 620): FoxP3 (Opal 570)` = 61, 
    `Num CD8 (Opal 480): PanCK (Opal 690): CD68 (Opal 780)` = 489, 
    `Num CD8 (Opal 480): PanCK (Opal 690): PD-1 (Opal 620)` = 2996, 
    `Num CD8 (Opal 480): PanCK (Opal 690): PD-1 (Opal 620): CD68 (Opal 780)` = 189, 
    `Num CD8 (Opal 480): PanCK (Opal 690): PD-1 (Opal 620): FoxP3 (Opal 570)` = 85, 
    `Num PD-1 (Opal 620): CD68 (Opal 780): FoxP3 (Opal 570)` = 43, 
    `Num PD-L1 (Opal 520): FoxP3 (Opal 570)` = 533, `Num PD-L1 (Opal 520): PanCK (Opal 690): CD68 (Opal 780): FoxP3 (Opal 570)` = 50, 
    `Num PanCK (Opal 690): CD68 (Opal 780): FoxP3 (Opal 570)` = 297, 
    `Num PanCK (Opal 690): PD-1 (Opal 620): CD68 (Opal 780): FoxP3 (Opal 570)` = 25, 
    `Num CD8 (Opal 480): PD-L1 (Opal 520): CD68 (Opal 780): FoxP3 (Opal 570)` = 32, 
    `Num CD8 (Opal 480): PD-L1 (Opal 520): PD-1 (Opal 620): CD68 (Opal 780): FoxP3 (Opal 570)` = 22, 
    `Num CD8 (Opal 480): PD-L1 (Opal 520): PanCK (Opal 690): CD68 (Opal 780): FoxP3 (Opal 570)` = 8, 
    `Num CD8 (Opal 480): PD-L1 (Opal 520): PanCK (Opal 690): PD-1 (Opal 620): CD68 (Opal 780)` = 210, 
    `Num CD8 (Opal 480): PD-L1 (Opal 520): PanCK (Opal 690): PD-1 (Opal 620): CD68 (Opal 780): FoxP3 (Opal 570)` = 13, 
    `Num CD8 (Opal 480): PanCK (Opal 690): CD68 (Opal 780): FoxP3 (Opal 570)` = 28, 
    `Num CD8 (Opal 480): PanCK (Opal 690): PD-1 (Opal 620): CD68 (Opal 780): FoxP3 (Opal 570)` = 6, 
    `Num PD-L1 (Opal 520): CD68 (Opal 780): FoxP3 (Opal 570)` = 80, 
    `Num PD-L1 (Opal 520): PD-1 (Opal 620): CD68 (Opal 780): FoxP3 (Opal 570)` = 39, 
    `Num PD-L1 (Opal 520): PanCK (Opal 690): FoxP3 (Opal 570)` = 238, 
    `Num PD-L1 (Opal 520): PanCK (Opal 690): PD-1 (Opal 620): CD68 (Opal 780)` = 291, 
    `Num PD-L1 (Opal 520): PanCK (Opal 690): PD-1 (Opal 620): CD68 (Opal 780): FoxP3 (Opal 570)` = 13, 
    `Num PD-L1 (Opal 520): PanCK (Opal 690): PD-1 (Opal 620): FoxP3 (Opal 570)` = 73), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
counts<- image %>%  rowwise(Image) %>% 
      summarise(
        "CD8"= sum(c_across(contains("CD8 ")), na.rm = TRUE),
        "CD8:PD-1"=sum(c_across(contains("CD8&PD-1")), na.rm = TRUE),
        "CD8:FoxP3"=sum(c_across(contains("CD8&FoxP3")), na.rm = TRUE)
      )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `intersect()` (and other set operations) and logical operators on tidyselect functions:

```
image %>% 
  rowwise(Image) %>% 
  summarise(
    "CD8"= sum(c_across(contains("CD8 ")), na.rm = TRUE),
    "CD8:PD-1"=sum(c_across(intersect(contains("CD8"), contains("PD-1"))), na.rm = TRUE),
    "CD8:FoxP3"=sum(c_across(intersect(contains("CD8"), contains("FoxP3"))), na.rm = TRUE)
  )
```

Or:

```
image %>% 
  rowwise(Image) %>% 
  summarise(
    "CD8"= sum(c_across(contains("CD8 ")), na.rm = TRUE),
    "CD8:PD-1"=sum(c_across(contains("CD8") & contains("PD-1")), na.rm = TRUE),
    "CD8:FoxP3"=sum(c_across(contains("CD8") & contains("FoxP3")), na.rm = TRUE)
  )

`summarise()` regrouping output by 'Image' (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 1 x 4
# Groups:   Image [1]
  Image   CD8 `CD8:PD-1` `CD8:FoxP3`
  <chr> <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
1 B07   54872      14561        2068
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `matches` tidyselect function. `matches` applies any arbitrary regular expression to select columns.

```
image %>%  rowwise(Image) %>% 
  summarise("CD8"= sum(c_across(contains("CD8 ")), na.rm = TRUE),
            "CD8:PD-1"=sum(c_across(matches("(CD8|PD-1).+(CD8|PD-1)")), na.rm = TRUE),
            "CD8:FoxP3"=sum(c_across(matches("(CD8|FoxP3).+(CD8|FoxP3)")), na.rm = TRUE))
## A tibble: 1 x 4
## Groups:   Image [1]
#  Image   CD8 `CD8:PD-1` `CD8:FoxP3`
#  <chr> <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
#1 B07   54872      14561        2068
```